# How to access variable defined in *ngFor?

Tags: javascript, angular, ngfor

In my first Angular 4 application, I defined a list component :

```
<edm-document *ngFor="let document of documents" class="column is-one-quarter"></edm-document>
```

`Document` is an interface :

```
export interface Document {
    id?: Number,
    name: string,
    filePath: string
}
```

All is working as expected, i.e I get my documents list. But now I would like to access to document variable inside my `DocumentComponent` (the `edm-document` tag component)

Inside my `DocumentComponent` template, if I try this it's not working :

```
<p>{{ document.name }}</p>
```

I get this error : `DocumentComponent.html:1 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined.`

I need to enforce document definition like this, and specify document as an input :

```
<edm-document *ngFor="let document of documents" [document]="document" class="column is-one-quarter"></edm-document>
```

Now it works but seems a bit redundant to me as I defined a `let` in loop. Does that mean the variable defined with `let` is only available in tag where `ngFor` directive is set ?

Am I missing something?

Thanks,

Nicolas

Comment: Yeah it is true that you can only acces the document variable in the edm-document tag and in all of its children.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> it works but seems a bit redundant to me as I defined a let in loop

It is not as redundant as it might seem, which becomes obvious when rewriting things a bit:

- When not explicitly defining what the component should use (with `[document]="document"` in your example) then how would your component know that the parent variable is named `document`? Consider:

  ```
  <edm-document *ngFor="let d of documents" [document]="d"></edm-document>
  ```

  One could argue that Angular could introduce some `parent` variable to access the outer loop variable, but then the component would know how it's going to be used, and could only be used in a loop. Reusable components should not be aware of that.
- How would it know that it can use that loop variable directly, and does not need some child property instead? Like:

  ```
  <edm-document *ngFor="let d of documents" [document]="d.text"></edm-document>
  ```

So: your code is just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Initially during DOM  rendering the documents object will `undefined`

- Use a typesafe `?` operator

  ```
  <p>{{ document?.name }}</p>
  ```
- Use a `*ngIf` with a array length condition as below,

  ```
  <span *ngIf="documents.length > 0"> 
     <edm-document *ngFor="let document of documents" [document]="document" 
                   class="column is-one-quarter"></edm-document>
  </span>
  ```

Answer (score 1):

well you can also do something like this

```
<edm-document *ngFor="let document of documents" class="column is-one-quarter">
 <span class="something">{{document.name}}</span>
</edm-document>
```

and in the edm-document.component.html do something like

```
<ng-content select=".something"></ng-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

The value (document) of the loop is valid inside of that block where the *ngFor placed. In your case between: `<edm-document>..</edm-document>`

In your example:

```
<edm-document *ngFor="let document of documents"class="column is-one-quarter">
<p>{{ document.name }}</p> <!-- document.name is valid -->
</edm-document>
<p>{{ document.name }}</p> <!-- document.name is invalid -->
```